# Can Anyone help me with Lagrange multiplier problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I need to find absolute maximum and minimum of thi function

$$F(x,y) = x^{2} - y^{2} - 2y$$
  over $$R = \{ (x,y)\ |\ x^{2} + {y^2} \leq 1\} $$

Thanks for help

Comment: Classify critical points in the interior, then look for boundary points where the gradient of $F$ is parallel to the normal vector field on the boundary of $R$.

Comment: Where exactly do you need help? Right now this looks like an ordinary "do-my-homework-for-me" question.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I am not a college student so no question of homework for me .i basically have found (0,-1) by equating $f_x$ and $f_y$ to zero but that doesnt seem to  be answer.I dont know why ?

Comment: It's not a Lagrange problem since the constraint is an inequality.

Comment: @coffeemath ??? Then how can it done if not lagrange problem

Comment: @Neal Thankyou .i think this is what i needed  . $(0,-1)$ doesnt satify $x^{2} + y^{2} \leq=1$ so i cant be interior critical point .Am i right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \rightarrow  \begin{cases}
 & \ -1 \leq x \leq1  \\ 
 & \ -1\leq y \leq1
\end{cases}$$now you have f=x^2-y^2-2y
$$f=x^2-(y+1)^2+1\\ $$and you have to find max , min f
$$x^2+y^2=1 \rightarrow x^2=1-y^2\\f=(1-y^2)-(y+1)^2+1 $$find f' then find roots of f'=0
then put roots in $$ f(y)=(1-y^2)-(y+1)^2+1$$ and chek f (y=-1 , 1) 
then you will have multiple numbers
greater ids max 
smaller is min

Answer (score 1):

No Lagrange is useful since the constraint is $x^2+y^2 \le 1.$ [Would need an equality constraint for LaGrange.] You have already found the only critical point of $F(x,y)$ happens to be $(0,-1),$ and this point is coincidentally on the boundary of $x^2+y^2 \le 1.$ The general method, when the region over which the max or min is sought happens to be closed and bounded (as it is here) is to find any critical points inside the region, and also find the max or min on the region's boundary. In your case the boundary may be parametrized for example by $x=\cos t,\ y=\sin t.$ Replace now $x,y$ in your objective function $F(x,y)$ by these formulas, and you have a one variable function to find the max and min of.

When this is done, the critical points come from the factorization of $g'(t)$ where $g(t)=F(\cos(t),\sin(t)).$ You should work it out, but one gets $g'(t)=-2(2\sin t+1)\cos t.$ This has four values of $t$ where $g'(t)=0$ which are fairly simple to express given the factorization.

At the four roots, two give $3/2$, one gives $1$ and the last gives $-3.$ so it seems the max is $3/2$ when $t=-\pi/6,\ 7\pi/6$ and the min is $-3$ when $t=\pi/2.$

Comment: the (0,-1) is found by interior point analysis  . ie by setting  $f_x$ and $f_y$ = 0  so is is true that it has to satify the inequality of region ie$ x^{2} + y^{2} \leq1$ ..which it doesnt .

Comment: Actually the point $(0,-1)$ satisfies $x^2+y^2=0^2+(-1)^2=1,$ so that it is in the region $x^2+y^2 \le 1.$ However it is in fact on the *boundary* of the region, which is why one can ignore it anyway for finding max/min, because one is going to parametrize the whole boundary anyway in this method.

Comment: In general you do use Lagrange multiplier to find the constrained extrema on the boundary. This time that is not necessary as we can use a parametrization instead or, simply eliminate $x$ by using the constraint - see Darya's solution.

Comment: @Jyrki Yes, one can use Lagrange on a boundary when that's a curve as here. (once no critical points inside has been shown).